# ggplot dodge bar not displaying when doing log coordinate transform

Tags: r, ggplot2, coordinate-transformation

I’m having problems with ggplot using coordinate transformations with a log10 scale. I wish to plot my data on a log10 axis, but without scaling the data itself. This works with sqrt, but when using a log axis coordinates no bars appear. Please can you tell me what I’m missing?

```
d <- data.frame(x=factor(c(1,1,2,2)), y=c(1,2,3,4), fill=factor(c(1,2,3,4))) 

#sqrt axis tranformaion works
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, fill = fill)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = y), stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  coord_trans(y = "sqrt")

#log10 axis tranformaion doesn't work
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, fill = fill)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = y), stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  coord_trans(y = "log10")

#log10 axis tranformaion works with points rather than bars
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, fill = fill)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = y), stat = "identity") +
  coord_trans(y = "log10")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `scale_y_log10` function:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, fill = fill)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = y), stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_y_log10()
```